# how to fix "yarn build" error in "node_modules" about agGrid?

Tags: angular, build, ag-grid, yarnpkg

I have error when i try to launch "yarn build" on my project.
with Angular 4.3.2

The error is in node_modules about agGrid.... O_O

> https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/23096645/63960733-7430cc80-ca8f-11e9-971e-6ec337b8d28a.jpg

I have also tried to exlcude it but in 2 files(agPanel.d.ts, agDialog.d.ts) about agGrid i have bad import:

```
declare const AgPanel_base: {
new (...args: any[]): {
[x: string]: any;
--> popupService: import("./popupService").PopupService;
--> gridOptionsWrapper: import("../gridOptionsWrapper").GridOptionsWrapper;
renderComponent?(): void;
config: any;
...
```

how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Could this be a versioning issue? Are you using the latest version of agGrid and, if so, is it compatible with such an old version of Angular?

Comment: it is compatible with my version of Angular....
i have find a workaround with change version of agGrid...
from 21.0.0 to 20.2.0...  but this is bad.... i have open issue on github, hope in one response.